# ERROR 1406 when importing a csv file to mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv

I encountered an error when trying to upload a CSV file to my database via the command-line interface.
The CSV file is structured as follows:

```
Id;price;shorttext;text
2020;24;foo;just a longtext for the product
2019;10;bar;"sometimes there are ; in the column"
2018;45;foobar;next longtext for the product
```

However, in the last column, I have the problem that the character ';' can occur in the text itself, so this column is sometimes specified with "..." as shown in the code above.

During the import I tried the following statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE product Fields OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' Terminated by ';' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But then I get an ERROR 1406: Data too long for column "text" at row 2. I think there is a problem because of the ';' in the text in the last column.

Do anyone know a solution, how to handle this optionally '"' in the last column?

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Fix your CSV data format. For example, alter the delimiter.

Comment: Is it possible your `text` column definition has less than 35 characters? And, following @Akina's suggestion, why not use the standard scheme for .csv files, with commas separating columns? You can probably find a library to help you write those files. .csv is a real mess in the wild, and wise programmers work hard to keep their own implementations simple and close to the standard.

Comment: So there is no solution to import the existing CSV file? :-( The single files are quite big and I thought there is still the possibility to import them at least for these files.
The character limit for the "text" column is 500 characters, that should be enough. The section above is also just an example, all columns contain more text than showed.